# Remove date from datetime in csv

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

for a project in python we need to use a csv file with several columns and create a ML model. My problem is, that one column is datetime, and the date is useless for the predictions, but i don't know how to remove it, as it is in the same column with the time like (so I can't just drop the column):

26.03.2018  00:00:00

Can you help me remove the date somehow? I tried different methods for handling 'datetime' but non worked so far.

```
data = pd.read_csv("TotalTrafo.csv")
dir(data)

type(data.Trafo1)

pandas.core.series.Series
```

Comment: if you know the column just use del to delete it

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
df['DateTime column']=df['DateTime column'].dt.time
```

to get only time .

Answer (score 0):

for a `datetime` object `foo` you can simply call `foo.time` to get only the time (foo.date for date, and so on)

If your pandas series does not contain `datetime` objects you can convert it to datetime by doing something like this

```py
data['Trafo1'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Trafo1'])

#or

data.Trafo1 = pd.to_datetime(data.Trafo1)
```